# C++ Primer 5th edition unions and members of class type

Tags: c++, class, initialization, copy-constructor, unions

Hello I have this from C++ primer 5th edition ch 19.6 unions:

> ```
> class Token {
> public:
>     // copy control needed because our class has a union with a string member
>     // defining the move constructor and move-assignment operator is left as an exercise
>    Token(): tok(INT), ival{0} { }
>    Token(const Token &t): tok(t.tok) { 
>        copyUnion(t); 
>    }
>    Token &operator=(const Token&);
>    // if the union holds a string, we must destroy it; see § 19.1.2 (p. 824)
>    ~Token() { if (tok == STR) 
>        sval.~string(); }
>    // assignment operators to set the differing members of the union
>    Token &operator=(const std::string&);
>    Token &operator=(char);
>    Token &operator=(int);
>    Token &operator=(double);
> private:
>    enum {INT, CHAR, DBL, STR} tok; // discriminant
>    union { // anonymous union
>       char   cval;
>       int    ival;
>       double dval;
>       std::string sval;
>    }; // each Token object has an unnamed member of this unnamed union type
>    // check the discriminant and copy the union member as appropriate
>     void copyUnion(const Token&);
>  };
> ```
>
> When we call `copyUnion` from the copy constructor, the union member will have been default-initialized, meaning that the first member of the `union` will have been initialized. Because our `string` is not the first member, we know that the `union` member doesn’t hold a `string`. In the assignment operator, it is possible that the `union` already holds a `string`. We’ll handle that case directly in the assignment operator. That way `copyUnion` can assume that if its parameter holds a `string`, `copyUnion` must construct its own `string`:
>
> ```
> void Token::copyUnion(const Token &t)
> {
>      switch (t.tok) {
>      case Token::INT: ival = t.ival; break;
>      case Token::CHAR: cval = t.cval; break;
>      case Token::DBL: dval = t.dval; break;
>      // to copy a string, construct it using placement new; see         
>      case Token::STR: new(&sval) string(t.sval); break;
>     }
> }
> ```

- The book doesn't show the implementation of the copy constructor but What matters me is; he said: "When we call `copyUnion` from the copy constructor, the union member will have been default-initialized, meaning that the first member of the `union` will have been initialized..." But I think that no member of a `union` object that is a part of a `class` is default-initialized so it must be explicitly initialized in the copy-ctor-init-list.

Here is my example:

```
struct A{
    A(){std::cout << "A()\n";}
    A(A const&){std::cout << "A(A const&)\n";}
    ~A(){std::cout << "~A()\n";}
};


struct Foo{
    Foo();
    Foo(Foo const&);
    ~Foo();

    enum {CLS_A, INT, CHAR} disc_; // discriminant 
    union {
        A a_; // first member is of class type that's defined its own def-ctor
        int age_;
        char degree_;
    };
};

Foo::Foo() :
    disc_(CLS_A), 
    a_(){ // explicitly initializing the member a_ otherwise it is not initialized

    std::cout << "Foo()\n";
}

Foo::Foo(Foo const&) : /*Foo()*/ { // a_ is not default-init so only if I un-comment the call the def-tor
    std::cout << "Foo(Foo const&)\n";
}

Foo::~Foo(){
    std::cout << "~Foo()\n";
    if(disc_ == CLS_A)
        a_.~A(); // not automatically called
}

int main(){

    Foo f;
    Foo f2 = f;
    
}
```

The output:

```
A()
Foo()
Foo(Foo const&)
~Foo()
~Foo()
~A()
```

- As you can `A`'s dtor called only once because member `a_` of `f2` object has not been initialized in the copy-ctor.

Now if I un-comment the call to the default-ctor `A()` from the copy-ctor:

```
    Foo::Foo(Foo const&) : Foo(){/*..*/}
```

The output:

```
A()
Foo()
A()
Foo()
Foo(Foo const&)
~Foo()
~A()
~Foo()
~A()
```

Here is his copy constructor:

```
 Token(const Token &t): tok(t.tok) { // didn't initialize any member of the `union`
   copyUnion(t); 
}
```

Now this OK. So What is meant with the `union`'s first member is default-initialized in the copy constructor in the book? Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to show more context about the book for us to be able to answer. What does the class look like? How about the union? Does your example match the code in the book exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is wrong. Since there is no default member initialiser for any variant member, and since there is no member initialiser for any variant member, there is no initialisation for any of the variant members. The first variant member is not active (nor any of the others).

Comment: Ok Thank you so much. I've been really struggling to understand it.

Comment: I've just delegated the initialization in my copy-ctor to the default-ctor for brevity.